# Kafka consumer client doesn't read the uncommitted message

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

There is a weird issue I have fallen into where I have created a kafka consumer in dotNet and have disabled the auto commit

```
config = new Confluent.Kafka.ConsumerConfig
            {
                BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
                GroupId = "Group1",
                AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest,
                EnableAutoCommit = false,
                AutoCommitIntervalMs=0,
                EnableAutoOffsetStore = false,  
        };
```

The idea here is to consume records in sequence and if the processing of a kafka record fails then do not commit that message and re-read the same message.

```
while(True){
//Consume the message -> c is my consumer

 cr = c.Consume(10);
 if(processCR(cr)){
       //do something
       c.Commit(cr)
 }
 else{
       //do something
       // do not commit the message
 }
}
```

Input

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

now suppose the record `5` fails
then the expected consumption is

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
5 // re-consume and process successfully
6
7
```

But the sequence is which I am actually getting is

```
0
1 
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

This is something weird and have been stuck in a loop
tried out multiple combination of config but nothing works.

Any lead is appreciated !!

Comment: Have you tried to use `seek(TopicPartition tp)` method after exception is thrown? I know that `EnableAutoOffsetStore = false` should disable store offsets locally after consume, but it is only one thing which comes to my mind.

Comment: Thanks for your input @PawełSzymczyk , But What I am exactly looking for is not to poll record from seek, and trying to understand why this doesn't work in dotNet

Comment: But does it solve your problem? :)

Comment: It works as a work-around, I tried the same with python/java module and it works as expected

Comment: Using seek enforces me to store and maintain the TopicPartition, making it a bit complecated

Comment: You have a topic and partition in the `ConsumerRecord`, at least in java implementation ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249426/discussion-between-bimal-gangawal-and-pawel-szymczyk).